# $ψ ◦ ϕ : G → K$ and $ϕ^{−1}$ is also an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that if $ϕ : G → H$ and $ψ : H → K$ are isomorphisms, then $ψ ◦ ϕ : G → K$ and $ϕ^{−1}$ is also an
isomorphism
I was able to show that $ϕ^{−1}$ is an isomorphism (since $ϕ$ is an isomorphism( bijection), then the inverse exists and is also a bijection so it's an isomorphism).
however I'm unsure about how to show  $ψ ◦ ϕ : G → K$ is isomorphism.

Comment: Show it is a hom, define an inverse, show the inverse is a hom

Comment: An isomorphism is a homomorphism which has an inverse homomorphism. That's all the info you know. From knowing that $\phi$ and $\psi$ have inverse homomorphisms, can you construct an inverse homomorphism for $\psi\circ\phi$?

Comment: Note that there are plenty of bijections between groups which are not isomorphisms, so your argument for $\phi^{-1}$ is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

So you know that the composition of invertible functions, yields an invertible function and that the inverse of an invertible function is an invertible function.

What you are missing *in both cases* is that the composition and inverse preserve your operations (i.e., are homomorphisms).

I'll assume (because of your letter choices) you are discussing *group* isomorphisms.

You need to show that $(\psi \circ \phi)(ab) = (\psi \circ \phi)(a) \cdot (\psi \circ \phi)(b)$ for all $a,b \in G$ to finish showing $\psi \circ \phi$ is an isomorphism (since you already know $\psi \circ \phi$ is invertible). This just involves expanding out what each $\psi \circ \phi$ term means and successively using first that $\phi$ preserves the operation and then $\psi$ does too.

You also need to show that $\phi^{-1}(ab)=\phi^{-1}(a)\phi^{-1}(b)$ for all $a,b \in H$. This is a little trickier.

Let $a,b \in H$. Consider $x=\phi^{-1}(a)$ and $y=\phi^{-1}(b)$. Then $\phi^{-1}(ab)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)\phi(y))$. Use the fact the $\phi$ preserves the operation and that $\phi^{-1}(\phi(thing))=thing$ to get $\phi^{-1}(ab)=\phi^{-1}(a)\phi^{-1}(b)$.